# Broken snippet rendering

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets, markdown, markdown-rendering

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75807496/uncaught-typeerror-table-rowsi-cellsj-queryselector-is-null) (in [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c7af5060-b130-4da1-aa4d-f9f950a61afa/view-source)) has a really weird StackSnippet content that doesn't want to display properly.

- In the question it renders nested scrollbars:
  [image]
- Scrolling down to the bottom of the outer container, we find the StackSnippet buttons, which have a broken layout as well:
  [image]
- Finally, in the [edit view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75807496/edit) we find only a small excerpt of the snippet in the preview:
  [image]

What is going on here? Are the many HTML comments confusing the parser? Is this a potential security issue that allows HTML injection?

Comment: The code snippet was indented as if it were code, code snippets shouldn't be indented.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Thanks. My meta search foo is not strong enough.

Comment: Also [Code snippet comments in code formatting break the formatting of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296441/1099857) on MSE. TLDR is that snippets and code blocks don't play well together.